# getting warning with this link of code

Tags: iphone

```
 -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
   [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"locationString %@",locationString);
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"listItems %@",[listItems objectAtIndex:2]);
    }
    else {
        //Show error
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}
```

StringWithContentsOfURL is deprecated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try instead of:
`NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];`

```
NSData *locationData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSString *locationString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:locationData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

the good thing about this way is that you can use NSURLConnection instead to get the data (asynchronously).

Answer (score 2):

If what made you confused is this "StringWithContentsOfURL is deprecated". A quick search in Apple's documentation shows that:

**stringWithContentsOfURL**:
Returns a string created by reading data from the file named by a given URL. (**Deprecated in iOS 2.0**. Use **stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:** or **stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:** instead.)

An example would be:

```
stringWithContentsOfURL:yourURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL
```